# Is there a refund webhook for Braintree?

Tags: braintree

I didn't find some `refund` webhook in [webhooks list](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/webhooks/overview).

Is **Disbursment webhook** something what can help me in this case https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/webhooks/disbursement/php ?

---

[Edit #1]: I've tested it and found that **Disbursment webhook** won't trigger after refund button is clicked in Braintree sandbox admin.

So I presume there is no webhook for refunds. For now I ended up with scheduled cron task to get refund transactions from the Braintree API:

```
$collection = Braintree_Transaction::search([
    Braintree_TransactionSearch::createdAt()->greaterThanOrEqualTo($hourAgo),
    Braintree_TransactionSearch::type()->is(Braintree_Transaction::CREDIT),
    Braintree_TransactionSearch::refund()->is(true)
]);
```

---

P.S. hey, downvoters, why wouldn't you argument your opinion in comments? At least it could be helpful for someone who will find this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

Braintree does not have a webhook which fires when a refund is created. Webhooks are used for **asynchronous events**—in other words, events which are not triggered directly by an API call made by your integration. You get immediate feedback on the success or failure of a refund via the [result object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/result-objects) from the refund API call. Use that result to trigger whatever action you wanted to take when a refund occurs.

(If what you're actually looking for is to get information when a refund transaction disburses—i.e., when the funds for a refund are moved out of your bank account—then you actually *do* want a [disbursement webhook](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/webhooks/disbursement). Disbursements represent the sum of your incoming and outgoing funds.)

Comment: Having webhooks for events such as refunds and successful/failed transactions allows for more granular control on the application side. For example, we might not need to implement a refund system on our end, instead refund transactions from the gateway and rely on the hook.

Comment: What poor reasoning for not including this webhook. Why not include as many webhooks as possible and then let application developers decide how they want to handle each one? In many cases a refund is issued through the BT web panel, not from an application. So how on earth is the application supposed to know about this???